# IN keyword not working when lowercase and coupled with query

Tags: mysql, sql

Server running Mysql (@@version: 5.7.29-32-57).

I noticed something strange when using the IN keyword in a SQL query.

When using `IN` in lowercase the query would not run properly and I couldn't understand why.

Here are examples:

```
    select id_g_type 
      from g_type 
     where g_type_parent = '5';
+-----------+
| id_g_type |
+-----------+
|         6 |
|         8 |
|        22 |
+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

```
 select id_g_doc
     , g_doc_type 
  from g_doc 
 where g_doc_folder = '782' 
   and g_doc_type;
+----------+------------+
| id_g_doc | g_doc_type |
+----------+------------+
|      690 |         90 |
|      691 |         90 |
|      692 |         19 |
|      693 |         22 |
|      694 |          8 |
|      695 |         81 |
|      696 |         81 |
+----------+------------+
7 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

And now when I try to use `IN` in lower case and upper case:

```
select id_g_doc 
  from g_doc 
 where g_doc_folder = '782' 
   and g_doc_type in 
       (select id_g_type from g_type where g_type_parent='5');

Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

```
select id_g_doc 
  from g_doc 
 where g_doc_folder = '782' 
   and g_doc_type IN
       (select id_g_type from g_type where g_type_parent='5');
+----------+
| id_g_doc |
+----------+
|      693 |
|      694 |
+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Is this some bug or am I missing something ?

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in a fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com

Comment: If confirmed, this would be a major bug in MySQL.

Comment: Can not reproduce here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a6f89c0d1ec700f2e80c1c1dca17cfcb Are you using the official mysql client?

Comment: Works well for me. See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cQngXqSvq6Vrxu2tFT56jd/0

Comment: In many cases I seem to remember a bug pretty clearly, but then doing the test again later does not reproduce it. Please do the following test for us: run the same query you have above with a lowercase in once and then with an uppercase IN. Compare the results against each-other and against your expectation and against what you remember about their past results. Thanks.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce with fiddle either. However I think the database system itself must be buggy or something. From time to time I get the error `ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away` when executing a request. The next request being sent solves this issue and the database reconnects. Furthermore I figured this wouldn't happen only with "IN" but with other keywords. The command line seem to be very instable after some tome.

Comment: I understand your point. But you should conduct the test I suggested on your system. If it's reproducing, then you have found something major, either limited to your system, or even something bigger. If it does not reproduce, then it's an issue with your system/network.

Comment: After reopenning the command line everything seem to work normally (with upercase or lowercase). I do not seem to understand what went wrong. I'll post again here when it happens again with the details I will have.

Comment: Seems buggy, but BTW, this query is much more likely to run fast as a join.  The performance of set-logic things like in, minus may not be as good, many not use indexes as well as a join.  Alternately, a corelated subquery "where exists(...)".  However, on a lucky day a good optimizer will make your query run the same as these.  If the join query could return duplicates, the others may sometimes eliminate them without the cost of a DISTINCT or the like.